# ImageView - Permanent change of default source image

Tags: android, android-imageview

My application is stated with default image for the an ImageView which i located at the Drawable folder.

As part of the application, the user have any option to replace default image with his own image from his Gallery.

I was able to retrieved an image from the Gallery and able to replace the default image but when the activity is re-invoke the default image is shown again.

My question is, how i permanent change of default source image to the chosen image so when application will be restarted or when the activity is re-invoke, it will present the new chosen image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save path of photo from gallery to `SharedPreferences` and with every run of the App, check if something is saved in `SharedPreferences`. If not, display default photo from `Drawable` but if there is something saved, take saved path and set it to `ImageView`.

Comment: Thanks...it is good idea. I have used the SharedPreferences and implement the required logic successfully.

Answer (score 0):

you just store retrieved image path in appPreference and put condition in Oncreate  that if  path is available from appPreference then replace image particular Activity